# Where is phpmyadmin installed on linux web server

Tags: centos

I have centos with cpanel whm.
I have phpmyadmin installed on whm.

i want to know where is the folder where phpmyadmin is installed

something like

/var/www/whm/phpmyadmin

Comment: what linux distribution are you running?

Comment: @Paul: Master is running CentOS

Comment: Mine was at: `/etc/phpmyadmin/`

Answer (score 6):

You need to look in the configuration file to see where it is set up.

Something like this will find it

```
find /etc/httpd/ -print0 | xargs -0 grep phpmyadmin
```

Which will return something like this

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/http.conf:    Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin
```

Or look for the folder itself

```
locate phpmyadmin
```

or

```
find / -type d -name "phpmyadmin" -print
```

Comment: Master, did you ever find your phpmyadmin folder? I installed phpmyadmin today form the repos and it was installed to /usr/share/phpmyadmin. It is likely to be the same location for you too.

Answer (score 2):

For cPanel/WHM server, below is the location for phpmyadmin

/usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin

It is not recommended to edit any files directly in a cPanel server, something may broke(Unless of course you know what you are doing).

Working of phpmyadmin is little bit different in cPanel, simply calling "mywebite.com/phpmyadmin" do not work in cPanel by default and can only access within from cPanel or WHM.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where it was installed. If you can access it via the web, you can find out by looking at your apache/favorite_httpd config files.